# Is a Reddit-like self-maintenance possible for a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

When a group grows too big maintenance of quality content becomes a serious issue.
It can be solved by man-power, but since we are programmers and the sole purpose of our existence is to replace that with our code, I don't accept that as an answer.

So I would like my group to maintain and moderate itself, for example like Reddit. Is there any workarounds you guys can come up?

Answer (score 2):

There are no workarounds.

a. Using a bot will be violation of the TOS
b. Browser extensions will reach rate limits

Whatever tools Facebook provides to you as a group admin are what you get.

Consider increasing your admin team number.